# php rename of ffmpeg deleted/reduced my video files to 20Kb

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm not sure what I did but somehow when I ran my code it deleted my video files, that is, it reduced each video file to a mere 20-40Kb.

I'm using a directory tree iterator to go through the selected folder and iterate all the files and subfolders in there, with commands for each. I'm only doing the files at this stage, and the code simply

1. renames the video file so that it has no spaces in it's name
2. extracts a thumbnail using ffmpeg and places it in the videos directory
3. inserts data in to database for displaying on a website.

Now I was able to use it once, and it worked save for 2 video files that I had been using for testing. For some reason those files were deleted. I tried running it again and it deleted all the videos.

What might be the problem?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "refit_2_admin", "asd123", "refit_2");
if($mysqli->connect_error)
{
    exit('Error db');
}
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
$_SESSION['mysqli'] = $mysqli;

// DIRECTORY

$dir = 'videos';

$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)); 
foreach($it as $path => $branch)
{
    if(is_dir($path)) // if is a directory
    {
        // echo something
    }
    if(is_file($path)) // if is a file
    {
        $schism = pathinfo($path);
        $string = str_replace(' ', '_', $schism['filename']);

        //$string = str_replace($replace, $with, $string);
        rename($path, $dir.'\\'.$string.'.mp4');

        $ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg.exe';

        $video = dirname(__FILE__) . '\\'.$dir.'\\'.$string.'.mp4';
        //echo ''.$video.'<br>';

        $image = dirname(__FILE__) . '\\'.$dir.'\\'.$string.'.jpg';
        //echo ''.$image.'<br>';

        $second = 1;

        /*$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1";
        if (preg_match('/Duration: ((\d+):(\d+):(\d+))/s', `$cmd`, $time)) {
            $total = ($time[2] * 3600) + ($time[3] * 60) + $time[4];
            $second = rand(1, ($total - 1));
        }*/

        $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";
        $return = `$cmd`;

        $video_title = substr($schism['filename'], 0, -5);
        $video_filename = $schism['filename'].'.mp4';
        $video_thumbnail = $schism['filename'].'.jpg';
        $video_include = basename(__DIR__);
        // Insert
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (video_title, video_filename, video_include, video_tags, video_thumbnail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $video_title, $video_filename, $dir, $video_title, $video_thumbnail);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

}
```

Comment: The high level description seems like you wrote the thumbnail *over* the video file.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I can't see how. The $video and $image variables are clearly pronounced, I can't see a mix up in them.

Comment: Is there a way to check for errors when `$cmd`; is run?

Comment: Echo your `$cmd` and run it alone to see if it works as expected.

Comment: Ahh, so I found that if I ran the script twice only then does it delete the video file. But it works once. The questions still remains as to why it's deleting the video file though, cause there are instances where I've to run it on the same file more than once.

Comment: $cmd works as expected. ffmpeg executing correctly looks like.